# Cifrar en C++ y ciclo

Tags: c++

Tengo un gran problema. Mi código ya cifra con el método *César* pero no logro que se realice 100 veces el cifrado con la misma variable mensaje. Por favor necesito saber donde tengo mi error o si mi ciclo esta mal.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  int contador = 1;
    while(contador<=100){
      string cadena = "Hola Mundo";
      string cadenacifrada = "";

      for(int i=0; i<cadena.length(); i++){
      cadenacifrada += (char) (cadena[i]+1);
      }
      cout << cadenacifrada << endl;//imprimir cadena
      return 0;
      contador++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tienes un `return 0;` justo antes de incrementar el contador que hace que tu programa termine en la primera iteración del `while`.

Answer (score 3):

```
return 0;
contador++;
```

Si el programa se encuentra un `return` abandona la función... luego **nunca** va a ejecutar el incremento de `contador`... y claro, abandonar la función implica también abandonar, necesariamente, el bucle `while`.

Quita ese `return 0` y tu programa hará las 100 iteraciones. Aunque yo reemplazaría ese `while` por un `for`:

```
for( int contador = 1; contador <= 100; contador++ )
{
  string cadena = "Hola Mundo";
  string cadenacifrada = "";

  for(int i=0; i<cadena.length(); i++){
  cadenacifrada += (char) (cadena[i]+1);
  }
  cout << cadenacifrada << endl;//imprimir cadena
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Olvida los bucles, usa [`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform):

```
string cadena = "Hola Mundo";
string cadenacifrada;

transform(cadena.begin(), cadena.end(),
    back_inserter(cadenacifrada),
    [](char c) { return c + 1; });
```

No hay necesidad de cifrar cien veces la cadena si el cifardo va a ser el miso todas ellas. Después de cifrada, muéstrala cien veces:

```
for (int i = 0; i != 100; ++i)
    std::cout << cadenacifrada;
```